# How can I convert MySQL query to laminas-db object format?

Tags: php, mysql, laminas

I have this MySQL query, I want to convert this query to Laminas-db https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-db/sql/#update

```
UPDATE
    table_a AS usa,
    table_b AS X,
    table_c AS ad
SET
    usa.account_no = ad.dea_license_num,
    usa.app_init_date = "2022-12-21",
    usa.app_submit_date = "2022-12-21",
    usa.status = 15
WHERE
    X.user_id = usa.user_id AND ad.address_id = X.legal_address_id AND usa.user_id = 1234 AND usa.supplier_id = 458
```

Looking forward for your valuable input